# 列名を列番号にしたい

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

基礎的な質問かもしれないのですが、
列名を指定するだけだと下のコードの `public string []{get; set;}`
`[]` の部分を変えるだけでカラム名を指定できると思うのですが、
列名＝列番号にしたい場合、どのようにすれば列を番号で表示することができるのでしょうか？
以下のコードに結合結果を格納しております。

```
code,name,number
A,B,C
A,B,C
```

実現したいこと

```
1,2,3
A,B,C
A,B,C
```

上記の列名についてはdataGridviewのカラムについてになります。

開発環境:
Visual Studio 2017

```cs
public class ResultDT
{
    public string code  {get; set;}
    public string name  {get; set;}
    public string number{get; set;}

}

protected void Result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List <OracleDT> oracleDTs = createOracleList();
    List<CsvDT> csvDTs = createCsvList();

    int i=1;
    var innnerjoin = from o in oracleDTs
        join c in csvDTs
        on o.code equals c.code
        select new ResultDT
        {
            code=o.code,
            name=c.name,
            number=i++
        }
    
    試したコード
    DataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "1";//エラー発生

    //ソース作成
    BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
    //ソースにinnnerjoin内のデータ挿入
    source.DataSource=innnerjoin;
    //DataGridViewにデータを挿入
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: これらが参考になるのでは？ [DataGridView.Columns](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_Columns), [DataGridViewColumn](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn?view=net-5.0), [DataGridViewColumn.HeaderText](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.headertext?view=net-5.0), [同.Name](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.name?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridViewColumn_Name)

Comment: 質問文の「列名」が具体的にどのような効果を求めているか不明確ですので、もう少し詳細に記述してください。

Comment: @sayuri  表を作成した際にカラムに当たる一行目を数字に置換えたいという意味になります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "1";//エラー発生
```

DataGridVierw.DataSource に BindingSource をバインディングする前に、存在しない列にアクセスしようとして例外が発生してます。

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

の後に HeaderText にアクセスしてください。列番号の設定は以下のようになるかと。

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in this.dataGridView1.Columns) {
    col.HeaderText = (col.Index + 1).ToString();
}
```

Comment: 定義前だったからエラーになったのですね。列番号も表示できました。ご回答ありがとうございました。